# Maybe I found something strange on pytorch, which result in property setter not working

Tags: python, pytorch, setter

Maybe I found something strange on pytorch, which result in property setter not working. Below is a minimal example that demonstrates this:

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class A(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.aa = 1
        self.oobj = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    @property
    def obj(self):
        print('get attr [obj]: {0}'.format(self.oobj))
        return self.oobj
    @obj.setter
    def obj(self, val):
        print('set attr [obj] to {0}'.format(val))
        self.oobj = val

class B(nn.Module):
    def get_attr(self):
        print('no any attr.')

class C:
    def get_attr(self):
        print('no any attr.')

b = A()             # set obj, and prints my setter message

b.obj               # get obj using my getter

# respectively run the following 3 lines, only the last line not call the setter I defined explicitly.
b.obj = C()         # set obj, and prints my setter message

# b.obj = [1, 2, 3]   # set obj, and prints my setter message

# b.obj = B()         # set obj, but it doesn't print my setter message
```

The last line doesn't call property setter I defined on class A, but call setter on torch.nn.Module. Because A
    regard B as a nn.Module, call the setter on nn.Module to set attr [obj] as a Module, but it still strange, why
    not call the setter I explicitly defined on class A?

#### And my project needs to set a nn.Module attribute via setter I defined explicitly, which causes BUG( because it failed). Now I change my code solved the BUG, but still puzzle with the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the outputs? Please elaborate in your question what exactly is going wrong

Comment: In all the cases it is calling the setter on `nn.Module`. I tried to expand on that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may not look obvious at first, but up until you set `b.obj` as a `nn.Module` object, you are defining a normal attribute; but once you set `b.obj` as a `nn.Module` object, then you can "only" replace `b.obj` with another `nn.Module`, because you registered it to `_modules`. Let me walk you through the code and you'll get it.

`nn.Module()`'s `__setattr__` implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L604-L646).

First, you defined a new `nn.Module`:

```py
b = A()  # btw, why not a = A() :)
```

Then, you set (I'll skip unnecessary steps to reproduce the behavior):

```py
b.obj = [1, 2, 3]
```

In this case, because

- `[1,2,3]` is [not a `nn.Parameter`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L611);
- You [haven't set a `nn.Parameter` as attribute](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L617) before;
- `[1,2,3]` is [not a `nn.Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L625);
- You [haven't set a `nn.Module` as attribute](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L631) before;
- You [haven't registered a buffer](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L639) before;

Then, this line will be execute:

```py
object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

which is nothing but a normal attribute set, **which calls your setter**.

Now, when you set:

```py
b.obj = B()
```

Then, because `B()` is a `nn.Module`, the following [block](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L624-L630) will be executed instead:

```py
modules = self.__dict__.get('_modules')
if isinstance(value, Module):
    if modules is None:
        raise AttributeError(
            "cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call")
    remove_from(self.__dict__, self._parameters, self._buffers)
    modules[name] = value
```

So, now you are actually registering a `nn.Module` to `self.__dict__.get('_modules')` (print it before and after and you'll see... do it before and after setting `[1,2,3]` as well).

After this point, if you are not setting a `nn.Parameter`, and you try to set `.obj` **again**, then it will fall into this [block](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/62f9312abdbc7aca510e17343028417ce53d7501/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L631-L636):

```py
elif modules is not None and name in modules:
    if value is not None:
        raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' as child module '{}' "
                        "(torch.nn.Module or None expected)"
                        .format(torch.typename(value), name))
    modules[name] = value
```

That is: you already have `modules['obj']` set to something and from now on you need to provide another `nn.Module` or `None` if you want to set it again. And, as you can see, because you are providing a `list` if you try to set `b.obj = [1,2,3]` again, you'll get the error message in the block above, and that is what you get.

If you really want set it to something else, then you have to delete it before:

```
b.obj = B()
del b.obj
b.obj = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right! But what I mainly puzzle with is the setter I explicitly defined failed to set nn.Module as a property. If nn.Module attribute can't set by my setter, there may be two property have the same name? One is @property I defined, another is a Module name?  There is no conflict?

Comment: @WeimingXiong as I said, **all** your calls first go to `__setattr__` of `nn.Module`. This is how Python works. As I tried to explain, it just happens that when the value is not a `nn.Module`'s object that **your** setter is used (because it is called from `nn.Module`). If you're not familiar with the order that Python uses for attributes (set and get), check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751159/4228275).

Comment: @WeimingXiong if this answer was useful somehow, consider upvoting it

Comment: @WeimingXiong I still can't see the _bug_. Everything is working as expected.